# Javascript Method Combinators

Tags: javascript

So, I've been reading up on some of Reginald's stuff on Method Combinators and I have to say, his style of writing is just not what I had hoped. Very smart, but I can't wrap my head around his explanations & usage. So, I was hoping all the very expressive bright minds here :-), can tell me if they've had some practical usage for method combinators.. and perhaps an example.

So, these are example of method combinators and outside of "feeding methods into other methods", I can't see what is the usage. I mean, I know we use this style alot in callbacks and such, but there is a deeper meaning/usage here that is escaping me.

https://github.com/raganwald/method-combinators/blob/master/README-JS.md

```
  var __slice = [].slice;

  this.before = function(decoration) {
    return function(base) {
      return function() {
        decoration.apply(this, arguments);
        return base.apply(this, arguments);
      };
    };
  };

  this.after = function(decoration) {
    return function(base) {
      return function() {
        var __value__;
        decoration.call(this, __value__ = base.apply(this, arguments));
        return __value__;
      };
    };
  };

  this.around = function(decoration) {
    return function(base) {
      return function() {
        var argv, callback, __value__,
          _this = this;
        argv = 1 <= arguments.length ? __slice.call(arguments, 0) : [];
        __value__ = void 0;
        callback = function() {
          return __value__ = base.apply(_this, argv);
        };
        decoration.apply(this, [callback].concat(argv));
        return __value__;
      };
    };
  };

  this.provided = function(condition) {
    return function(base) {
      return function() {
        if (condition.apply(this, arguments)) {
          return base.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      };
    };
  };

  this.excepting = function(condition) {
    return function(base) {
      return function() {
        if (!condition.apply(this, arguments)) {
          return base.apply(this, arguments);
        }
      };
    };
  }
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A sample of AOP/Method Combinators usage with MVVM**

First, let you have a business model which triggers a long operation (in coffee):

```
class A
    operation: -> promise
```

It has a member which start to chat with backend and returns a [promise](https://www.promisejs.org/).

You need show a loading splash (or make some fields disabled) while the operation is in progress. Sure, it is not a responsibility of business process, because it is related to view model, not to business model.

You write something like in your view model (in coffee):

```
buildA = ->
    a = new A()

    a.operation = after a.operation, (result) ->
        showSplash()
        return result.then (v) ->
            hideSplash()
            return v

   return a
```

And then when you will need an instance of the view model with bound view logic to business logic you just write (in coffee):

```
a = buildA()
```

That is it!

---

**Where it should be useful a lot?**

Sure, it is usable for tests. Usually when you separate concepts your tests become easy to write and support.

For example, when you need to change your business logic you change only your business model (and add tests only for that). When you need to change your view logic you change only your view model (and add tests only here). If you will not separate concepts for your code that code will be hard to support and testing.

*divide et impera!*